# Array.concat() returns separate arrays in typescript(Angular)

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to apply a filter on a JSON array using multiple input parameters from a checkbox and concatenate the results into a single array.

```
stats = {
    All : {value: 'All', prop: 'All', checked: true, disabled: false},
    Open : {value: 'Open', prop: 'Open', checked: false, disabled: false}, 
    Registered: {value: 'Registered', prop: 'In Progress', checked: false, 
                 disabled: false}, 
    Admitted: {value: 'Admitted', prop: 'Student Admitted', checked: false, 
                   disabled: false}, 
    Inactive: {value: 'Inactive', prop: 'Converted', checked: false, 
                   disabled: false},
         }; 
    check: boolean = true; disable: boolean = true;
    checkedStatus =[];
    filtered = [];


//inside function//

if(checkerObj.checked === true){
    this.checkedStatus.push(checkerObj.prop);
    this.checkedStatus.forEach(el => {
     var temp = [];
     let temp2 = [];
     temp = this.rows.filter(row => {
      if(row.statusValue === el){
        temp = [];
        //console.log(typeof row);
        return row;
      }
      });
      //console.log(temp);
      var arr3 = temp2.concat(temp);
     //this.source = new LocalDataSource(temp2);
     console.log(arr3);
    })
  }
```

The code prints multiple array declarations on screen, which would have been fine if every consecutive declaration had the value of previous concatenated into it.

```
enquiry-manage.component.ts:131
 (17) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 
      {…}, {…}, {…}]
enquiry-manage.component.ts:131 
 (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
enquiry-manage.component.ts:131 
 (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I have fetched data into the array by use of a service:

```
this.enquire.getAllEnquiry().map(data => {
  this.rows = data;
 }).subscribe(data => {
  this.source = new LocalDataSource(this.rows);
  this.source.refresh();
})
```

then only checkbox check event

```
  statusFilter(checkerObj){
   if(this.stats.Open.checked === true || this.stats.Registered.checked === 
   true || this.stats.Admitted.checked === true || 
   this.stats.Inactive.checked === true){
   this.stats.All.checked = false;
   this.stats.All.disabled = true;    
   if(checkerObj.checked === true){
    this.checkedStatus.push(checkerObj.prop);
    this.checkedStatus.forEach(el => {
     var temp = [];
     let temp2 = [];
     temp = this.rows.filter(row => {
      if(row.statusValue === el){
        temp = [];
        return row;
      }
      });
      //console.log(temp);
      temp2 = temp.concat(temp2);
     //this.source = new LocalDataSource(temp2);
     console.log(temp);
    })
  }
  else if(checkerObj.checked === false){
    var index = this.checkedStatus.indexOf(checkerObj.prop);
    if (index > -1){
      this.checkedStatus.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.checkedStatus.forEach(el => {
    //          this.customFilterStatus(el);
    })
    //      console.log(this.checkedStatus);
  } 
  }
```

Comment: [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=b) always returns a new array. Whats the issue? May be you need `if (checkerObj.checked === true) {
 this.checkedStatus.push(checkerObj.prop);
 let temp2 = this.rows;
 this.checkedStatus.forEach(el => {
  temp2 = temp2.filter(row => {
   return row.statusValue === el
  });
 })
 console.log(temp2);
}`

Comment: @Satpal actually I was hoping to merge the incoming array into the previous one. Also tried [].push.apply() but the same output.

is there any mean by which i can merge these three array i got as output into one

Comment: @Satpal the above code would be perfect if I was providing a single input, but if I filter an already filtered row then on the second input an empty array will print out.

Comment: Please share the complete code, Important line is `let temp2 = this.rows;` Please it at correct location

Comment: It's more like on a table I am providing input via checkboxes to filter a particular column and on multiple selections, I would get a single array as output  for all these parameters.

Comment: Actually, the main issue is that I am getting a separate array "temp" on each element of the "checkedStatus" which I wish to merge into a single array. If it were static arrays then [].concat() works perfectly but these arrays are created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Well tried the suggestion provided by @Satpal and modified the code a bit inside the function.

```
    if(checkerObj.checked === true){
    this.checkedStatus.push(checkerObj.prop);
    let temp2 = []; 
    let temp = [];
    let arr = [];
    this.checkedStatus.forEach(el => { 
      temp2 = this.rows.filter(row => { 
        return row.statusValue === el }); 
        temp = temp2;
        arr = arr.concat(temp);
      });
      this.source = new LocalDataSource(arr);
      console.log(arr);
  }
```